How to combine two channels while preserving the order of elements in nested lists
Here's a puzzle:
Given are two Nextflow channels, ch_a and ch_b:
ch_a = Channel.from([
    [['a0', 'b0', 'c0'], 'x0'],
    [['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], 'x1'],
    [['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], 'x2'],
    [['a3', 'b3', 'c3'], 'x3'],
    [['a4', 'b4', 'c4'], 'x4'],
    [['a5', 'b5', 'c5'], 'x5'],
])

and

ch_b = Channel.from([
    ['a0', 'aa0'],
    ['b0', 'bb0'],
    ['c0', 'cc0'],
    ['a1', 'aa1'],
    ['b1', 'bb1'],
    ['c1', 'cc1'],
    ['a2', 'aa2'],
    ['b2', 'bb2'],
    ['c2', 'cc2'],
    ['a3', 'aa3'],
    ['b3', 'bb3'],
    ['c3', 'cc3'],
    ['a4', 'aa4'],
    ['b4', 'bb4'],
    ['c4', 'cc4'],
    ['a5', 'aa5'],
    ['b5', 'bb5'],
    ['c5', 'cc5'],
])

The task is to combine the channels ch_a and ch_b to obtain the following result:
desired_ch = Channel.from([
    [['a0', 'b0', 'c0'], 'x0', ['aa0', 'bb0', 'cc0']],
    [['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], 'x1', ['aa1', 'bb1', 'cc1']],
    [['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], 'x2', ['aa2', 'bb2', 'cc2']],
    [['a3', 'b3', 'c3'], 'x3', ['aa3', 'bb3', 'cc3']],
    [['a4', 'b4', 'c4'], 'x4', ['aa4', 'bb4', 'cc4']],
    [['a5', 'b5', 'c5'], 'x5', ['aa5', 'bb5', 'cc5']],
])

Each element of the resulting channel consists of two parts, the first part being identical to the corresponding element of ch_a, and the second being a list (such as ['aa0', 'bb0', 'cc0']) of partial ch_b elements grouped and sorted to match the order of the first subelement in each ch_a element (in this example, the order of elements in ['a0', 'b0', 'c0']). The objects a0, b0, c0, etc. from ch_b are identical to the corresponding objects in ch_a. They guide the sorting of the appended list ['aa0', 'bb0', 'cc0'], but are themselves omitted from the result. Basically, this merging operation augments ch_a by selecting, reordering, restructuring, and then appending elements of ch_b according to the contents of the first subelement of each ch_a element.
The additional objects (such as 'x0') do not affect the merging and are only included to illustrate that the (potentially complex) structure of each ch_a element is preserved by this operation.
Assume that the merging operation does not leave any remainder, ie. the mapping between 'a0', ..., 'c5' in ch_a and in ch_b is a homomorphism.
In the example, channel elements are conveniently ordered so that the relationships between the two channels are obvious. Naturally, any given Nextflow run will permute the elements of both channels in such a way that ch_b elements which need to be grouped together may end up being far apart from one another.
Tried the following:
result = ch_a
    .merge(
        ch_a.map{ it[0] } 
        .flatten()
        .combine(ch_b, by: 0)
        .map{ it[1] }
        .collate(size=3)
    ){ a, b -> [a, b] }
    .map{ [it[0][0], it[0][1], it[1]] }

Here's the result:
result.view()

[[a0, b0, c0], x0, [aa0, bb0, cc0]]
[[a1, b1, c1], x1, [aa1, bb1, cc1]]
[[a2, b2, c2], x2, [aa2, bb2, cc2]]
[[a3, b3, c3], x3, [aa3, bb3, cc3]]
[[a4, b4, c4], x4, [aa4, bb4, cc4]]
[[a5, b5, c5], x5, [aa5, bb5, cc5]]

While this transformation generates the desired output for the current simple example, there are a few problems with this solution:

It looks clumsy. There must be a more succinct way to do it.
More importantly, it uses a fixed value 3 in .collate(size=3). It would be much more desirable to evaluate this number dynamically, on a per-element base, so that a more general staggered case can be handled as well. What's the best way to do that?
Another generalization: what if, instead of a single 'x0' or 'x1', etc., a ch_a element contains multiple additional nested sub-elements? In that case, the hardcoded indexing it[0][1] might no longer suffice. Replacing it[0][1] with it[0][1..-1] (with or without .flatten()) gives the undesired [x0] instead of the desired x0. How do I fix that?


Given the example, the solution that first comes to mind is:
workflow {

    combined = ch_a.transpose().join( ch_b ).groupTuple( by: 1 )

    combined.view()
}

Results:
$ nextflow run main.nf 

 N E X T F L O W   ~  version 24.10.0

Launching `main.nf` [peaceful_mayer] DSL2 - revision: ec04256bc6

[[a0, b0, c0], x0, [aa0, bb0, cc0]]
[[a1, b1, c1], x1, [aa1, bb1, cc1]]
[[a2, b2, c2], x2, [aa2, bb2, cc2]]
[[a3, b3, c3], x3, [aa3, bb3, cc3]]
[[a4, b4, c4], x4, [aa4, bb4, cc4]]
[[a5, b5, c5], x5, [aa5, bb5, cc5]]


However, this won't suit the general case where each list item in the first channel can contain additional elements, for example:
ch_a = Channel.from([
    [['a0', 'b0', 'c0'], 'x0'],
    [['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], 'x1', 'y1', 'z1'],
    [['a2', 'b2', 'c2'], 'x2'],
    [['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3'], 'x3'],
    [['a4', 'b4', 'c4'], 'x4', 'y4'],
    [['a5', 'b5', 'c5'], 'x5'],
])

ch_b = Channel.from([
    ['a0', 'aa0'], ['b0', 'bb0'], ['c0', 'cc0'],
    ['a1', 'aa1'], ['b1', 'bb1'], ['c1', 'cc1'],
    ['a2', 'aa2'], ['b2', 'bb2'], ['c2', 'cc2'],
    ['a3', 'aa3'], ['b3', 'bb3'], ['c3', 'cc3'], ['d3', 'dd3'],
    ['a4', 'aa4'], ['b4', 'bb4'], ['c4', 'cc4'],
    ['a5', 'aa5'], ['b5', 'bb5'], ['c5', 'cc5'],
])

The solution is to collect these (one way is using the Groovy tail() method), and call groupTuple() on the collection, for example:
workflow {

    ch_a
        .transpose()
        .map { tuple( it.head(), it.tail() ) }
        .join( ch_b )
        .groupTuple( by: 1 )
        .view()
}

Results:
$ nextflow run main.nf 

 N E X T F L O W   ~  version 24.10.0

Launching `main.nf` [irreverent_goldwasser] DSL2 - revision: 19f6531687

[[a0, b0, c0], [x0], [aa0, bb0, cc0]]
[[a1, b1, c1], [x1, y1, z1], [aa1, bb1, cc1]]
[[a2, b2, c2], [x2], [aa2, bb2, cc2]]
[[a3, b3, c3, d3], [x3], [aa3, bb3, cc3, dd3]]
[[a4, b4, c4], [x4, y4], [aa4, bb4, cc4]]
[[a5, b5, c5], [x5], [aa5, bb5, cc5]]


Note that since we have not specified the size option when calling groupTuple(), the operator will not emit any groups until all inputs have been received. If these channels are not the output of a factory method and are actually downstream of one or more processes, it is usually preferable to specify the number of expected elements in each group using the size option. This lets each group be emitted as soon as it’s ready. In cases where the size of each group varies, you can use the built-in groupKey() function to define the expected size of each group, for example:
workflow {

    ch_a
        .map {
            def size = it.head().size()

            tuple( it.head(), groupKey( it.tail(), size ) )
        }
        .transpose()
        .join( ch_b )
        .groupTuple( by: 1 )
        .map { key_list, groupkey, vals ->

            tuple( key_list, groupkey.toList(), vals )
        }
        .view()
}

